# QDate into QString

Tags: python, string, pyqt4, qdate

I have a question about PyQt4. I have a date that is of a type QDate and I want to simply turn it into a string format as opposed to QDate format. For example, if the date is 09/16/2013, I would want to change it into a string form of September 16, 2013 if possible.

I played around with toString but I think that only works with C++ (unless I am mistaken).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdate.html#toString) is your friend ;)

```
>>> date = QtCore.QDate.fromString('20130916', 'yyyyMd')

# PySide
>>> date.toString('MMMM d, yyyy')
u'September 16, 2013'

# PyQt4
>>> date.toString('MMMM d, yyyy')
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'September 16, 2013')
>>> unicode(date.toString('MMMM d, yyyy'))
u'September 16, 2013'
```

Comment: @user1871869 What are you exactly doing? `print date`? If you wan't to print it you **have** to convert it to string somehow. You can do it either by explicitly calling the `toString` method or just printing it which uses the built-in `__str__` which just prints out the type and numbers.

Comment: I have one question--when I was trying to print out this date, I was given an error saying: requires string as left operand, not QString

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Wow, nevermind this worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help! It also makes a lot of sense also! Thank you!!!